# UIViewContentModeScale mode of the cell image change silently after the cell is touched(highlighted)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

EDIT:

I get the issue fixed by create a customize cell.(However, still have another [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788197/dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-always-return-non-nil).) But why the default cell does not work is still a mystery...

Cory 's answer did not fix the issue but `clipsToBounds` is really a point and I appreciated his continuous help. So I give him the bounty but not accept his answer as the answer. The answer still in the wind....

================================

I set the `UIViewContentModeScale` mode of the cell image to `AspectFill` (left image) and the image was correctly displayed(Fill the image view but keep the aspect). However, after touch and hold on the cell, image's will change: the imageView's frame and contentViewMode are changed. (see the first cell of the left image below )

This is really wired and I can believe such as basic thing could goes wrong so there must be some stuff I was missing out.

Environment: Xcode 4.3 iOS5.1 simulator & device.
[image]

UPdate:

I set the UIViewContentMode using the inspector of the storyboard.

And by the way ,I used SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h.

UPdate2:

I set explicitly the content mode in the code but issue still there.
[cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

update4:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AlbumCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"AlbumCell"];

    }
    //[cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    //[cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Album *album = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [album.title description];    
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.userVisiableDateFormatter stringFromDate:album.releaseDate];


    //[cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:album.coverThumbnailUrl]
                placeholderImage:[self placeHolderImage]];

}
```

[image]

Comment: In what method do you set the content mode?  Show us the source of that method.

Comment: @rob I set the attribution using the attribution inspector from the storyboard.

Comment: Try using scaleToFill content mode

Comment: This question maybe trivial but I want to make sure I understand. The cell's imageView changes content mode after you select it, go to detailedView, and return?

Comment: @mrunal: AspectFill is what I need.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to find a couple of different things that might be the problem.

First it try setting the clipsToBounds property:

```
img1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; 
img1.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

The second is:

The reason you don't see a difference between those modes is that the UITableViewCell automatically sizes its image view to fit the aspect ratio of the image. The content modes only come into play when the view's aspect ratio is different from the image's.

Either override layoutSubviews in your custom UITableViewCell class or create an image view yourself (don't use the one that the table view cell provides).

EDIT 1:

After looking at your code the problem may lie in how your handling your cell configuration. Pointers maybe getting released when they shouldn't. Try these 2 options:

Option 1:
Keep your current method of passing off configuration to a new method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AlbumCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"AlbumCell"];

    }

    return [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* returnCell = cell;

    Album *album = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    returnCell.textLabel.text = [album.title description];    
    returnCell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.userVisiableDateFormatter stringFromDate:album.releaseDate];


    [returnCell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [returnCell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    [returnCell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:album.coverThumbnailUrl]
                placeholderImage:[self placeHolderImage]];

    return returnCell;
}
```

Option 2: (my recommendation)
Configure the cell in the delegate method. It's ok to do this here and it's not bad practice. This is delegate method is there to configure the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AlbumCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"AlbumCell"];

    }


    Album *album = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [album.title description];    
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.userVisiableDateFormatter stringFromDate:album.releaseDate];

    [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:album.coverThumbnailUrl]
                placeholderImage:[self placeHolderImage]];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: +1. However, I set the clipstoBounds to true but the issue still there.

Comment: Are you using custom cells or defaults ones? I am trying to recreate the error myself to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: i was using the default cell.

Comment: Hmmm rather strange. I can't seem to recreate the error. Could you post your tableView delegate that returns the cell? Maybe some small problem there.

Comment: IMHO, your code is same as the original one. Anyway, I tried (the 2nd suggestion) but no luck. I am think there may be something wrong with the default cell and I will try custom cell.

Comment: Technically if you pass a pointer off to a new method you should return a new reference pointer if you wish to use it further. Code integrity.

Answer (score 3):

set the same image for highlighted state also .

Answer (score 3):

it could be the case that you need to set your auto-resizing (or struts & springs, if you have learned that terminology).

in an app in which i have a custom cell with an image on the left similar to yours, i have my autoresizing set up as in the following picture:

[image]

note that i have it set up so that the size remains constant within the cell frame, and that the top, bottom and left size are commanded to hug those edges with that much gap on each side.

aside from that, i believe you are right that aspectFill is the choice for that setting.  clipToBounds really shouldn't matter; it will only be necessary if that view were a subview of another view in which it was supposed to appear where it's size was larger than the view it is a subview of.

Comment: note also that i am using a custom cell for this.  it's been a while, but i seem to recall having similar issues w.r.t. being able to establish the "whitespace" on the top, bottom & left as i desired using the default cell.  if you are interested in having the whitespace and specific square image view, you may have to do the same thing to guarantee what you want.  if you are happy with filling the space with the image but want the initial image to also fill the space, you may have to use a larger default image in your cell image field.  anyway, my custom cell was pretty easy to create.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue for a subclassed UITableViewCell with a subclassed UIImageView property. Changing the name of this property from 'imageView' to something else fixed the problem for me.